# LINQ2SQL: how to merge two columns from the same table into a single list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

this is probably a simple question, but I'm only a beginner so...

Suppose I have a table containing home-work locations (cities) certain people use.
Something like: ID(int), namePerson(string), homeLocation(string), workLocation(string) where homeLocation and workLocation can both be null.

Now I want all the different locations that are used merged into a single list. Something like:

```
var homeLocation =
from hm in Places
where hm.Home != null
select hm.Home;

var workLocation =
from wk in Places
where wk.Work != null
select wk.Work;

List<string> locationList = new List<string>();
locationList = homeLocation.Distinct().ToList<string>();
locationList.AddRange(workLocation.Distinct().ToList<string>());
```

(which I guess would still allow duplicates if they have the same value in both columns, which I don't really want...)

My question: how this be put into a single LINQ statement?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `FirstQuery.Union(SecondQuery).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: @George a `Union` maps to `UNION`, and is implicitly distinct already (contrast to `Concat`, which maps to `UNION ALL`, and preserves duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var all = homeLocation.Union(workLocation).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... knew it had to be something simple... But can the first two queries also be combined in some way?

Comment: @TomL If you watch the SQL trace (or hook `ctx.Log = Console.Out;`), I would **hope** that LINQ-to-SQL is already composing these into a single query. LINQ-to-SQL is pretty aggressive about query-composition

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'm using LinqPad and the LINQ translates to this :
 SELECT [t2].[value]
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX),[t0].[Home]) AS [value]
    FROM [Places] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[Home] IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX),[t1].[Work]) AS [value]
    FROM [Places] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[Work] IS NOT NULL
    ) AS [t2]
But for some reason it still seems kind of 'verbose' so to speak...